# Show for |x|<1:

Tags: analysis, summation, partial-fractions

If |x|<1 show that:

$\sum_{k=1}^∞ kx^k = \frac{x}{(1-x)^2}$

I know that I should use partial fraction expansion. But don't really understand how to do it.

Comment: Factor one $x$ out of both sides. Integrate what remains. If you really want partial fraction expansion, you know you can write $$\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}=\frac{a}{1-x}+\frac{b}{(1-x)^2}$$ Then identify $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Other hint: differentiate the power series for $\frac{1}{1-x}.$